# How to make launcher in VS Code use my virtual environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Here is a little python script that demonstrates the problem.

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
print('okay')
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
```

When I run it from the terminal within VS Code, it works as expected:

```
(.default) saul@linuxBox:~/Projects/PythonProjects/medSched$ python test.py
3.10.4
okay
```

When I run it with the launcher (Run..Run Without Debugging) it fails:

```
(.default) saul@linuxBox:~/Projects/PythonProjects/medSched$  cd /home/saul/Projects/PythonProjects/medSched ; /usr/bin/env /bin/python3.10 /home/saul/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 39803 -- /home/saul/Projects/PythonProjects/medSched/test.py 
3.10.4
okay
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saul/Projects/PythonProjects/medSched/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 69, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

The terminal knows to use my virtual environment, but the launcher apparently does not, because if I run `python3.10 test.py` in the global environment, I get the same error.  Can you tell what have I done wrong?  How do I fix it?

Comment: I would recommend to ask in the `ms-python` repo why they choose the command `/bin/python3.10` while there is a virtual environment active

Comment: @rioV8 After this hint, I figured out how to fix it, though maybe not the best way.

Comment: Please see the fix I posted in my answer.  I would be glad if someone would tell me what the proper way to do things is.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix.  In the command menu, I went to `Python: Select Interpreter` and entered the path to the interpreter in my virtual environment, `/home/saul/.virtualenvs/.default/bin/python`  That works now, but I don't know if I've set it for this project or all projects.  There must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: you can see in the `.vscode/settings.json` if has changed global or only for this workspace. This is correct, if you select a python interpreter that is in a subdir of the workspace folder (virtual environment) then VSC will find it and show it in the Pyton Interpreter List, and activate the environment when you create a terminal, you always have to select the interpreter to use, I have multiple Python version installed and multiple Virt Envs and always select the correct Python Interpreter

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks.  I'll remember to do that from now on, and if I forget, I'll know what to do.